# Difference in behaviour between primary constructors in F# classes and structs?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2013

If I try this type definition in Visual Studio Express 2013, I get an error:

```
type Foo(bar : int) =
   struct
      member x.bar = bar
   end
```

If I change it so that it is a class instead, I don't get any errors:

```
type Foo(bar : int) =
   class
      member x.bar = bar
   end
```

The error I get is:

```
The member 'bar' can not be defined because the name 'bar' clashes with the field 'bar' in this type or module"
```

The error goes away if I change the constructor parameter's name slightly. I understand the differences between CLR structs and classes in general, but I don't quite understand the reason for this difference in behaviour. Can anyone explain it?

I'm mostly asking in case the answer dispels some deeper misunderstanding that I have about F#. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I can't find a pertinent reference in the spec offhand, a little experimentation with a decompiler shows that primary constructor parameters on structs are always compiled as fields with the same name. For classes, a more complex set of rules (see [§8.6.1.3](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818937)) is used to determine their compiled form, which includes munging field names when they would otherwise clash with members.

Compare the compiled forms of this struct and class:

```
type S(bar: int) = struct end

type C(bar: int) =
    member x.bar = bar
```

```
public class C
{
    internal int bar@12;

    public int bar
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bar@12;
        }
    }

    public C(int bar)
    {
        this.bar@12 = bar;
    }
}

public struct S : IEquatable<Program.S>, IStructuralEquatable, IComparable<Program.S>, IComparable, IStructuralComparable
{
    internal int bar;

    public S(int bar)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

The struct's primary constructor parameter is compiled as a field (and assigned!) even though it's unused. The class, on the other hand, allows a member and parameter with the same name. Admittedly, this doesn't explain *why*, but may help to clarify the observed behavior.

Comment: As you said, this doesn't explain why, but it's still great to know what's actually going on. Thanks!